# How to pull and loop the data in R studio?

Tags: r

It would be great if some one could help on below requirement.
[image: Hive Database Table]

My requirement is pull the data from Hive table based on "Fiscal Quarter" and load it to txt file. Process should be like loop, i would expect 3 txt files (FY19Q1_Txtfile1.txt/FY19Q2_Txtfile2.txt/FY19Q3_Txtfile3.txt) with 3 iterations.

Comment: You could may be provide us some example data, or some code explaining what you are trying to achieve. You question is difficult to understand right now.

Comment: A better question might be "Should I use a loop to do this?", to which most people would say: "No".

Comment: @Gowachin:- I hope attached sample data helps to explain my requirement !

Comment: Well it has been worse, but take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. The point isn't to make us look at the data, but provide us a way to copy it easily, for experimenting with it.

Comment: @Gowachin:- My bad, going forward will make sure to provide the details to copy easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your table is stored as a data.frame on R, named data for example, you can do that :

```
write.csv(data[data$Fiscal_Quarter == 'FY19Q1'], 'FY19Q1_Txtfile1.txt')
write.csv(data[data$Fiscal_Quarter == 'FY19Q2'], 'FY19Q2_Txtfile3.txt')
write.csv(data[data$Fiscal_Quarter == 'FY19Q3'], 'FY19Q3_Txtfile3.txt')
```

And if you want to use a loop instead :

```
for (i in 1:3){
    file_name = paste('FY19Q', i, '_Txtfile', i, '.txt',sep="")
    FQ = paste('FY19Q', i, sep="")
    write.csv(data[data$Fiscal_Quarter == FQ], file_name)
}
```

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: :- Thanks for your efforts, your code helps me a lot.

Comment: With help of your code finally i have implemented my requirement and it's working well. Below is my working script to pull the data from Hive database table and load to txt file.  library(odbc)
library(data.table)
#Connecte to Hive Database by using ODBC driver
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "HiveODBCDNSName")

#Retrive unique months from Table
UniqueMonths <- dbSendQuery(con, "select distinct fct.partition_year_month from schemaName.tablename fct where fct.record_source = 'Sales' ;")
Df_UniqueMonths <- dbFetch(UniqueMonths)

Comment: #Loop the Months to Hive SQL query and genrate the extract for Month
sqlQry <- "select * as CountofRecords from schemaName.tablename fct where fct.record_source = 'Sales' and fct.partition_year_month = '"
Location <- "E:\\Software Repository\\R\\rProjects\\Data\\chnl_Sales_"
for (sMonth in Df_UniqueMonths$fct.partition_year_month) {
  qry <- paste0(sqlQry, sMonth, "' ;")
  ExtractLocation  <- paste0(Location,sMonth,".txt")
  MonthWiseQuery <- dbSendQuery(con, qry)
  MonthWiseData <- big.matrix(dbFetch(MonthWiseQuery))
  fwrite(MonthWiseData,ExtractLocation,sep = "|",quote ="auto")}